# H1 goes behind the background image

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want the h1 header to stand over background image, with a background color that looks like a box for the header. However all the changes I make on h1 stay behind the background image and only show for a millisecond before the background image appears on top of it. How do I fix this?

```css
#all{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    position: absolute;
top:0px;
left: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 2000px;
    background-image: url(../webtekodev/background.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
  

}

.header {
    padding: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #1abc9c;
    color: white;
  }
  
.row {   
    f display: -ms-flexbox; 
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap; 
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
 

.sag{

    -ms-flex: 30%;
    flex: 30%;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    padding: 20px;
}
.orta{
    -ms-flex: 40%; 
  flex: 40%;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
}
.sol{
    -ms-flex: 30%;
    flex: 30%;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> this is the title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stiller.css">
    </head>

    <body>
//header
<div class="header">
    <h1>jjjjjjjjjjj</h1>
    <p> jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj </p>
</div>
//navigasyon barı
        <div id="all">
            <div class="navbar">
                <a href="anasayfa.html">Ana Sayfa</a>
                <a href="birimlerimiz.html">Birimlerimiz</a>
                <a href="hakkımızda.html">Hakkımızda</a>
                <a href="iletişim.html">İletişim</a>
              </div>

//containerlar
              <div class="row">
<div class="sag">dsf</div>
<div class="orta">ddd</div>
<div class="sol"> wdwq </div> 
    </div></body>
</html>
```

Also the div columns that I try to build somehow doesn't stay side by side, but instead, below each other. It worked before I added the background image. What do I do wrong?

Comment: If you [edit] your snippet and use a dummy image site (e.g., https://loremflickr.com/) to get a URL to an image, we could probably see what you're talking about at bit easier.

Comment: Nothing to do with your problem, but comments in HTML are like this `<!-- you comment here -->`. The way you are trying to add comments actually renders those "comments" in the page.

Answer (score 1):

just give `z-index: 1;` to `h1`.
Have a look at [this](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp):

Comment: You need to position the h1 too, don’t you?!